# How to keep WPF MessageBox on top if instanciated in separate thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, messagebox

I try to show a message box on top of my other windows as well as other applications that are running. Since i must ensure that this call is not blocking any operation in my application i use a separate thread to show the message box.
My problem with the following implementation is that the message box is not on top of the main application, it is always hidden/behind my main window.

```
 Task.Run(() =>
              {
                  var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, e.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                  OnMessageConfiration(dialogResult);
              });
```

**Application.Current.MainWindow** as parameter for the WindowOwner does not work for this implementation since it throws an Exception because its not running in the UI thread i guess.

Is there any other solution to achieve my goal?

Comment: all UI elements calls **must** be called from UI-thread

Comment: @vasily.sib thx for your comment, but it doesn't answer my question at all. There might be reasons to call it from elsewhere. If you have a solution by doing that without calling from another thread I would be happy if you share it with me.

Comment: you should read more about [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)

Comment: there is no reason to call for UI from another thread then UI-thread. It is called **UI**-thread for reasons. Also, there is no reason to perform long-running task on UI-thread, they should be in background. That's why there is a [Dispatcher class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher) [TPL (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) and **async** keyword

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dispatcher` to show messagebox.

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "T", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }), null);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who run in to the same problem and don't want to work through the fragments of an answer provided in the comments:

```
    try
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = await ShowMessageBoxAsync(e.Message);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            _log.InfoFormat("acknowledged");
        else
            _log.InfoFormat("no acknowledge");
    }


    public async Task<MessageBoxResult> ShowMessageBoxAsync(string message)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
          return Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information));
        });
    }
```

That is the way to not bloc the calling thread and keep the message box on top of the main window of the application.

Thanks to vasily.sib for his hints.